# What is the difference between Mughals and Afghanis?

Tags: india, mughals

I was reading India history. There is a description that Babur battled with Ibraham Lodhi ,and finally he won. As per my knowledge Babur is basically Mughal, and his native was Afghanistan. Similarly, Behlol Lodhi was from Afghanisthan. Behlol lodhi son was Sikandher Lodhi, and Ibraham Lodhi was there son. Ibrahma Lodhi was very cruel. The Mughal and Ibrham Lodhi both were from Afghanisthan but one is called Mughal and other is called Afghani. I am a bit confused on it. Can someone please throw some light on it?

Comment: Did you see the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babur) article on Babur? He was from Uzbekistan, descended from the Timurid Dynasty. [Ibrahim Lodhi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibrahim_Lodi) was a [Pashtun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pashtun_people).

Comment: Afghan Pashtuns were supposed to antagonize the Mughals. They were each other's rivals. Examples are Sher Shah Suri, Ahmad Shah, Khushal Khan, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Actually Babur was not Afghan.

Babur was a descendant of Tamurlane on his father's side and Genghis Khan on his mother's. He inherited Ferghana, a valley in Uzbekistan, where he is still revered.

The word Mughal is the Persian version of the word Mongol. He was actually Turco-Mongol, meaning he had Turkic and Mongol ancestry.

(Please note that many Central Asian states speak languages related to Turkish and so are related to the Turks. In fact, the Turks actually were supposed to have originated in Central Asia.)

Tamerlane was a Turk but claimed to be a Mongol, and a descendant of Genghis Khan, to be fearsome. They spoke language called Chagatai. Tamur's and Babur's biographies are written in that language.

Babur did conquer Kabul after being thrown out of his native Uzebkistan. He loved Kabul dearly and it became the only homeland he was left with after losing hope of recovering his original homeland.

The Lodhis are ethnic Pashtun and are not related to Babur.

Comment: Basically, Lodhi belongs to Afghanisthan, and Mughals can be said as from USSR - broadly. Because, Uzbekistan was once upon a time in USSR.

Comment: I don't know why you want to make an emphasis on USSR. That time Uzbekistan was independent from Russia. Russia, on the other hand, was divided into many principalities. Either way, culturally, they were similar to Turkey and Iran. And there was no concept of communism at all.